# Next.js build fails using <img> tag

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I recently started making websites with Next.js, and I have been using a mix of `Image` and `img` for various use cases.

I know that `Image` is built-in to `Next.js` and is the better choice, but there are scenarios where I do not know the size or the ratio of the images I am loading, and thus the `img` seems to better suit.

During my recent project, this is the first time my `npm run build` command is failing with:

```
1:7  Error: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.
```

My other Next.js projects do not fail this way, and use the same `next.config.js`. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. - Next.js using html tag <img /> ( with styled components )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203582/error-do-not-use-img-use-image-from-next-image-instead-next-js-using-ht)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to the new Next.js release, which has integrated ESLint with its own set of rules to enforce that `<Image>` should always be used. Your other projects don't fail because probably you are not using Next.js v11, or they may have their own ESLint config, where you haven't extended `next`. Ref.: [nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint)

You can ignore linting during build by this:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  eslint: { ignoreDuringBuilds: true },
  // your other settings here ...
}
```

If you want to specifically disable the rule for a file or just a line do this: (can be done in two clicks if using ESLint extension in VSCode)

```js
{/* eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-img-element */}
<img ... //>

// for whole file, add this to top:

/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */

// for a section:

/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
// your code here...
/* eslint-enable @next/next/no-img-element */
```

You can also disable the rule using [`.eslintrc`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/):

```json
{
  "extends": "next",
  "rules": {
    "@next/next/no-img-element": "off",
  }
}
```

You can also ignore (all rules for) a complete file using `eslintignore` or `ignorePatterns`. Please refer: [eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code)

Comment: Amazing - this worked, thank you for this answer!