# Deploying to Vercel surfaces Next.js errors that I didn't receive during development, how to fix them earlier?

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, next.js, eslint, vercel

I just started trying to deploy to Vercel recently, and every time I push I have to check the errors during the build, only to find stringent typescript errors or other errors like "Can't use `<img>` tag, please use next/image" sorts of things. How can I get these errors during development so I don't have to wait til the build step only to find out after a few minutes there is an error, fix it, wait another few minutes, fix the next error, etc. How can I just get all these errors during development, like making it so my app won't compile locally somehow. Right now during development everything compiles fine, just when I push and it goes to Vercel build it starts throwing these errors.

How do I get the errors to display during development, and prevent compilation during `npm run dev` during development, instead of during `npm run build`? Also, I would like to be warned in my editor about possible errors in advance if possible, so I can fix them right there before facing them.

Comment: Firstly, this is not a TypeScript error. It is an ESLint error, [which can be easily disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68173768/11613622). Secondly, you can run `next build` on your local setup to check for the build errors before hand. [Refer docs.](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production)

Comment: That doesn't help, I want it to be run during `npm run dev` while it's watching files for changes.

Comment: Try adding `plugin:@next/next/recommended` to your existing ESLint config `extends` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To verify your application will build locally before pushing, you can run `next build`.
2. To disable ESLint from failing your build, you can [turn it off](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint).

Comment: New link to docs for turning eslint off: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/eslint