# How to get image height and width properties in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I just want to know how can we let an image take its own height and width using `<Image>` component in Next.js, instead of defining height and width by ourselves?

Answer (score 6):

Beginning from [Next.js v11](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11#automatic-size-detection-local-images), you can simply do:

```js
import Image from 'next/image';
import foo from 'path/to/foo.png';

// ...

<Image src={foo} alt="" /> // <-- no need to pass height/width
```

In the above example, `foo` will be an [object](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/eb871d30915d668dd9ba897d4d04ced207ce2e6d/packages/next/image-types/global.d.ts#L4-L9) containing `src`, `height`, `width` (and optionally `blurDataURL`). So, if you want to access them, you can do stuff like `foo.height`, etc.

---

Also, there are a few *hacks* that may interest you:

1. Use [`layout="fill"`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout) and pass a handler to [`onLoadingComplete`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#onloadingcomplete), where you will get [`naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) and [`naturalHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight). Then you can set the state to adjust the container accordingly. But this approach is not recommended as it will likely increase CLS.
2. In data fetching methods [[`getStaticProps` (static generation)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) / [`getServerSideProps` (SSR)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)], read your image files and pass their dimensions as a prop to your components. SSR may cause an overhead on your server resources, but that can be minimized significantly by caching.
3. Simply use your good old `img` tag. Again not recommended, but will work if your files are already optimized. ESLint may throw some warning depending on your configuration, you would need to disable those rules.

---

PS: Just check once if your use-case can be handled by `layout="fill"` (without updating state).

Just a clarification - on older threads on SO, GitHub, etc., you may see an `unsized` prop being passed to `next/image`. It was deprecated in Next.js v10, and removed in v11. So, its probably not gonna work for you.

---

References:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching
- https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production
- [Get the width and height of an image in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12539918)
- [Next.js build fails using <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68170138)
- [How to use Image component in Next.js with unknown width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66353475)
- https://web.dev/cls
- https://web.dev/time-to-first-byte

---

[A sample implementation of the second hack:](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lehmann-vk753?file=/pages/index.js)

```js
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

import Image from "next/image";
import probe from "probe-image-size";

const IndexPage = ({ mountains }) => (
  <Image
    src="/mountains.jpg"
    height={mountains.height}
    width={mountains.width}
    alt="Mountains"
  />
);

const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const mountains = await probe(
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(process.cwd(), "public/mountains.jpg"))
  );
  return { props: { mountains } };
};

export default IndexPage;
export { getStaticProps };
```