# How to set Next js Image with and height the same like in the original image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js

I'm trying to create an image gallery with a Masonry-like layout. It means the layout contains a few columns and with the same width and amount of columns depends on the current viewport width. The height of every item is flexible and depends on the Image that will be rendered in the particular gallery item. So the item wrapper doesn't have any limits for height but the width is limited

Previously I used the simple `img` tag  for every gallery item to render the image

```
<img src={src} alt={description} />
```

and it renders itself with the Width and Height the same as the original image has and it's exactly what I want because it renders itself with the various height and thus masonry layout works as it should.

So far so good but I'd like to use the Next.js Image component because it has a lot of nice features like lazy loading, loading blur placeholder, etc. however I can't figure out how to achieve the same behavior as in the standard `img` use case. 
 
I can't use the `layout="fill"` with the `width & height = 100%`  because the parent container of the item doesn't have any height

```
<Image
  width="100%" height="100%"
  layout="fill"  
  src={src}
  alt="Picture of the item"
/>
```

The image itself must be a "height-dictator" for the parent container and also I can't use the direct with/height values to set into the Image component because these properties are unknown for each image

So I'm wondering if it is possible at all to achieve this behavior in the case of Next.js Image component?

I'll appreciate any help & info!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69344756/11613622

Comment: hi @brc-dd I checked it but it doesn't work in my case because I don't know the Height of every image so I was wondering about the same possibility to automatically render the image using it's natural height like the standard `img` html tag does

Answer (score 2):

Width and height in next/image Component should be integers without units. And they are pixels. layout="fill" is a different story. The width and height property could be calculated using JS if this is the only possibility you have.

Here are some cool ways to deal with that:
[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

All you have to do is run the calculation before attaching the image to the Image component.

what you are looking for is naturalWidth and naturalHeight of the image.

Comment: hi @Bartek B. So, as I understand, there is no possibility to achieve the same behavior as in the case of the plain `img` HTML tag. Gush, so pity I must do it manually. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Actually as  
brc-dd mentioned in the comment it might not be required to do at all. But if you want to have 100% control over it that should be possible to achieve. // Updated oh... saw your comment

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach doesn't work. I've already tried. Without `layout="fill"` Next.js throws an error **Error: Image with src ... must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property.** and if I set the `layout="fill"` property it just starts to fill the image regarding the **parent container** width/height and it isn't good as the Parent container doesn't have any height. The image itself should dictate what height should parent container have